# Doorkeeper ActiveRecord::NotNullViolation on "application_id" (password grant)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oauth-2.0, doorkeeper

I'm trying to setup [Doorkeeper](https://github.com/doorkeeper-gem/doorkeeper) for my API (using the password grant flow) but whenever I try to retrieve an access token I'm getting the following error on my rails server:

```
ActiveRecord::NotNullViolation (PG::NotNullViolation: ERROR:  null value in column "application_id" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (1, 1, null, e24EH4dNKBNoHh7OSzzyT_7Cg4Ka52e9TB4TP-vz4aM, null, 7200, null, 2019-07-19 22:50:44.797045, , ).
: INSERT INTO "oauth_access_tokens" ("resource_owner_id", "token", "expires_in", "created_at", "scopes") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING "id"):
```

I followed Doorkeeper's [rails getting started guide](https://doorkeeper.gitbook.io/guides/ruby-on-rails/getting-started) except for the last step for adding associations to my User model -- I tried doing so after running into the error but that didn't help. I'm not currently using [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise).

Did I not configure something correctly? Or maybe I have to use Devise? I'm not exactly sure where the `application_id` field plays in as the documentation for doorkeeper has the page for applications left [blank](https://doorkeeper.gitbook.io/guides/concepts/application).

What I sent to the API:

```
grant_type: password
username: test@user.com
password: password
```

My doorkeeper.rb initializer file:

```
Doorkeeper.configure do
  # Change the ORM that doorkeeper will use (needs plugins)
  orm :active_record

  # This block will be called to check whether the resource owner is authenticated or not.
  resource_owner_authenticator { current_user || render(status: 401) }

  resource_owner_from_credentials do |_routes|
    user = User.find_by_email(params[:username].try(:downcase))
    user if user && user.authenticate(params[:password])
  end

  grant_flows %w[password]
end
```

My doorkeeper migration file:

```
class CreateDoorkeeperTables < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :oauth_applications do |t|
      t.string  :name,    null: false
      t.string  :uid,     null: false
      t.string  :secret,  null: false

      # Remove `null: false` if you are planning to use grant flows
      # that doesn't require redirect URI to be used during authorization
      # like Client Credentials flow or Resource Owner Password.
      t.text    :redirect_uri, null: false
      t.string  :scopes,       null: false, default: ''
      t.boolean :confidential, null: false, default: true
      t.timestamps             null: false
    end

    add_index :oauth_applications, :uid, unique: true

    create_table :oauth_access_grants do |t|
      t.references :resource_owner,  null: false
      t.references :application,     null: false
      t.string   :token,             null: false
      t.integer  :expires_in,        null: false
      t.text     :redirect_uri,      null: false
      t.datetime :created_at,        null: false
      t.datetime :revoked_at
      t.string   :scopes
    end

    add_index :oauth_access_grants, :token, unique: true
    add_foreign_key(
      :oauth_access_grants,
      :oauth_applications,
      column: :application_id
    )

    create_table :oauth_access_tokens do |t|
      t.references :resource_owner, index: true
      t.references :application,    null: false

      # If you use a custom token generator you may need to change this column
      # from string to text, so that it accepts tokens larger than 255
      # characters. More info on custom token generators in:
      # https://github.com/doorkeeper-gem/doorkeeper/tree/v3.0.0.rc1#custom-access-token-generator
      #
      # t.text :token, null: false
      t.string :token, null: false

      t.string   :refresh_token
      t.integer  :expires_in
      t.datetime :revoked_at
      t.datetime :created_at, null: false
      t.string   :scopes

      # If there is a previous_refresh_token column,
      # refresh tokens will be revoked after a related access token is used.
      # If there is no previous_refresh_token column,
      # previous tokens are revoked as soon as a new access token is created.
      # Comment out this line if you'd rather have refresh tokens
      # instantly revoked.
      t.string   :previous_refresh_token, null: false, default: ""
    end

    add_index :oauth_access_tokens, :token, unique: true
    add_index :oauth_access_tokens, :refresh_token, unique: true
    add_foreign_key(
      :oauth_access_tokens,
      :oauth_applications,
      column: :application_id
    )

    # Uncomment below to ensure a valid reference to the resource owner's table
    # add_foreign_key :oauth_access_grants, <model>, column: :resource_owner_id
    add_foreign_key :oauth_access_tokens, <model>, column: :resource_owner_id
  end
end
```

My user model:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  before_save { email.downcase! }
  validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
  # VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = (removed for this post)
  validates :email, presence: true, length: { maximum: 255 },
                    format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
                    uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
  has_secure_password
  validates :password, presence: true, length: { minimum: 6 }
end
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Create a doorkeeper application.

   - None-API mode: Simply navigate to /oauth/applications/new
   - API mode: You can create the application from rails console:

     `application = Doorkeeper::Application.create(
       name: "ApplicationName",
       scopes: "read write",
       confidential: false,
       redirect_uri: "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob"
     )`
2. Now you can use `application`'s `uid` (`client_id`) and secret to request an access token. Example `curl` request for the `password flow`:

   ```
   `curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost:3000/oauth/token?client_id=CLIENT_ID&client_secret=SECRET' --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --header 'Accept: application/json' --data-raw '{"username": "example@email.com", "password": "password", "grant_type": "password" }'`
   ```
3. Other flows (like `Authorization` flow) requires you to get an `authorization` token that you can use to request `access token`s. Relevant wiki: https://github.com/doorkeeper-gem/doorkeeper/wiki/Authorization-Code-Flow

Comment: Hi! I am using password grant type and it seems, before having the access_token, user need to login first with email and password together with client_id and client_secret for it to work. But in order to acquire client_id and client_secret, user MUST have a doorkeeper application first. 
WHEN is the best place to create the doorkeeper application? In the /register or /login? Should I have a separate route for doorkeeper application creation?

Because of course, the doorkeeper app creation should not be visible nor included in the user's UX.

What is your strategy? Many Thanks!

Comment: @Welp I'm not sure you understand the purpose of doorkeeper applications. Each client application of your authentication provider is associated with a Doorkeeper application. Example: I have an API which serves two client applications, a web app and an android app. So I have created two Doorkeeper applications, each one is associated with one of the client apps. I could've used one Doorkeeper application for both of then, but I wanted to use different flows and configurations for the two clients. 1/3

Comment: Now in my case, I do not intend to open my authentication provider (or API) for third party app usage. So I disabled Doorkeeper application creation routes. See: https://doorkeeper.gitbook.io/guides/configuration/skip-authorization 2/3

Comment: If you don't want that, and want to support third part applications, you'd just use the routes that Doorkeeper gives you. Make sure of course that you did not use the skip_authorization configuration option. Or you could provide you own application creation page. 3/3

Comment: Just remember that an application is associated with a client application, not a user.

Comment: So how should I handle if a user has multiple clients? for example, user has an android app client and ios app client but logged in same account. should it have a 2 doorkeeper oauth application?

Comment: what if another user has 2 android phones and each has an app installed. so each client should have a doorkeeper OAuth app?

Comment: When should the creation of the Doorkeeper OAuth App take place?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205985/discussion-between-welp-and-user5252279).

Comment: I am referring to this link https://github.com/doorkeeper-gem/doorkeeper/wiki/Associate-users-to-OAuth-applications-%28ownership%29 reason why I think application is associated within user. 1/2

Comment: Just like the facebook app. If you have sessions in your laptop, iphone and android and you visit https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=security&section=sessions&view you will have 3 sessions which you can revoke. Please enlighten me  2/2

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Password Credentials Grant flow, you must comment on the application_id reference in the oauth_access_tokens table alone, not the oauth_access_grants

Answer (score -2):

uncomment this:

```
add_foreign_key :oauth_access_grants, <model>, column: :resource_owner_id
```

and change

```
t.references :application,    null: false
```

to

```
t.references :application,    null: true
```